# Horizontal ScrollView and Tabs - native base

Tags: javascript, react-native, native-base

I'm using horizontal `ScrollView` and `Tabs`.

but I have a problem.
this is my view:

```
 <Tabs>
     <Tab heading="A">
        <ScrollView horizontal={true}> 
           //items
        </ScrollView>
     </Tab>
     <Tab heading="B">

     </Tab>
</Tabs>
```

when I want to scroll between Items, my tabs will change. how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

solved:

```
<Tabs locked={true} ...
```

Answer (score 1):

setting `locked={true}` for Tabs components it worked for me. but still it is a bug very annoying.